# Any good use case for force:source:deploy -o?

Tags: deployment, salesforcedx

According to [Develop Against Any Org](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_develop_any_org.htm), there's a new (at least new to me since Summer '19) option `-o` for the sfdx deploy command as follows:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -o
```

Documentation says:

> Regardless of whether the deployment contains errors (not recommended if deploying to a production org)

What would be a good use case for this?  And would there be any good use case to ever deploy to production for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For production, it seems to only apply to deployments that do not fail because of unit tests. For example, if you deploy a bunch of fields and a page layout, and one field fails to deploy, the layout will also fail, but the remaining fields may succeed. It allows a partial update to happen. For Sandboxes, this can be very important, as it allows you to ptoentially deploy broken changes to the Sandbox so you can fix them.